# Can I perform dataframe operations on different levels?

Tags: pandas

I have a multi-indexed dataframe (indexed on customer and year).  I'd like to know the difference between years on the customer level.  I could reset the index, perform a groupby, but that seems like a lot.

Is there a way to perform something like `df.diff` based on level?

For instance, here`merchant` and `year` are an index.  Can I find the difference in members using dataframe operations?

```
merchant    year    Members 
A   2015    10  
A   2016    20  
B   2015    11  
B   2016    7   
C   2015    1   
C   2016    0
```

Expected output

```
  merchant  year    Members 
A   2015    Nan 
A   2016    10  
B   2015    Nan 
B   2016    -4  
C   2015    Nan 
C   2016    -1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by level `merchant` with `diff`:

```
df = df.groupby(level='merchant')['Members'].diff().reset_index()
print (df)
  merchant  year  Members
0        A  2015      NaN
1        A  2016     10.0
2        B  2015      NaN
3        B  2016     -4.0
4        C  2015      NaN
5        C  2016     -1.0
```

Comment: Ok, thanks that works.  Half way between what I wanted and what I thought of doing.

Comment: Yes, exactly. First I think you need `print (df.index.get_level_values('year').to_series().groupby(df.index.get_level_values('merchant')).diff())` and it is a bit ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `unstack()` function

```
df['Members'] = df['Members'].unstack('merchant').diff().stack()
```